# How to use executeScript called by javascript (bridge) in webview (javaFX)

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx, javafx-2

I have this class:

```
public Palco()  {
    super();
    initComponents();
    setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

}


private void initComponents() {
    createScene();

    progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

    JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
    topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
    topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);


    statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
    statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getContentPane().add(panel);

    setTitle("My App");

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();

}

private void createScene() {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            WebView view = new WebView();
            engine = view.getEngine();
            engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


            engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                         String title = null;
                        public void run() {
                            if(newValue == null){
                              title = "Carregando...";
                            } else {
                              title = newValue;
                            }
                            Palco.this.setTitle(title);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {

                public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                           // lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            txtURL.setText(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                             if(newValue.intValue() < 100){
                                 statusBar.setVisible(true);
                             } else {
                                 statusBar.setVisible(false);

                             }
                            progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());

                        }
                    });
                }
            });


            engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
                 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc) {
                     MainTiles tiles = new MainTiles(engine);
                    tiles.ShowCategory(0);


                }
              });

            engine.getLoadWorker()
                    .exceptionProperty()
                    .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                            if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                     public void run() {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                                panel,
                                                (value != null) ?
                                                engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage() :
                                                engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                                "Loading error...",
                                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

           engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                   new ChangeListener<State>() {
                       @Override
                       public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                           State oldState, State newState) {
                           JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                           jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());


                       }

                       }
               );

            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
        }
    });
}

public void loadURL(final String url) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String tmp = toURL(url);

            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
            }

            engine.load(tmp);
        }
    });
}

private static String toURL(String str) {
    try {
        return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
    } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return null;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Palco browser = new Palco();
            browser.setVisible(true);
            String url = getClass().getResource("html/index.html").toExternalForm();
            browser.loadURL(url);
       }     
   });
}


public static void changeScene(){

}
```

And I wanted execute the command `executeScript` in JavaScript (bridge) callback `<a onclick="java.link()">teste</a>`, but I dont know how pass the webview (`WebView.getEngine`) in class Bridge:

```
public void link(){
    executeScript(engine, "document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = 'test';"); // engine is WebView

}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible or how to do?

Sorry my english is very bad =/, I'm Brazilian!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could it pass it via a constructor, it's a normal Java object which can be shared, i.e.

```
public class Bridge{
    WebEngine engine;    // add a new field

    public Bridge(WebEngine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

// ...

JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge(engine));   // pass it here
```